# Step in evaluation of integral for Green's function of Klein-Gordon equation.

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, greens-function, klein-gordon-equation

I am looking at the various ways to derive explicit position-space expressions of the Green's function with certain boundary conditions (Feynman propagator) of the Klein-Gordon equation. In this particular example, I cannot figure out why, when integrating by parts, the boundary term, i.e., the $uv$ in $\int u dv = u v - \int v du$, disappears. The result of the whole process is, as usual, a modified Bessel function. I know there are multiple different methods to perform this integration; I understand these and am not interested., i.e., through contour integration, or Schwinger parameterization, I specifically want to know why, on the second line on the below, that we discard the evaluated term from the IBP?

[Method of the integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO4zd.png)

Whenever I try I get something like

\begin{equation}
uv = \left[ \left( -\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2 + m^2}} \right) \cos kr \right]^{\infty}_{0} = [-1\cdot \cos\infty] + 0. 
\end{equation}

Comment: The original integral is divergent. I think this whole calculation has to be interpreted in a distributional sense for which the boundary term at $\infty$ will vanish by considering the inner product with compactly supported (or rapidly decaying) functions.